# How to write on Manifest file for Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a script that extracts the questions and answers of a quiz created in Google Forms. However, I am having difficulty creating the add-on.

The following is the function:

```
function myFunction() {
  // TODO: try to get another form by ID
  //var form1 = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var form1 = FormApp.openById('1OLu1xIL6qThi44Y9NJddE-TdBxIA4_Txj7M9z_oxKlU');
  //var form1 = FormApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1OLu1xIL6qThi44Y9NJddE-TdBxIA4_Txj7M9z_oxKlU');
  var items = form1.getItems();
  console.log("total questions: " + items.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    //console.log(item.getType() === FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE);
    //console.log(item.getType());
    var x = 0;
    console.log('***** New Question *****');
    switch(item.getType()) {
      case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
        this.extractMultipleChoice(item);
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
        this.extractCheckbox(item);
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.PARAGRAPH_TEXT:
        this.extractParagraphText(item);
        break;
      case FormApp.ItemType.TEXT:
        this.extractText(item);
        break;
    }
  }
}
function extractMultipleChoice(item) {
  var question = item.asMultipleChoiceItem();
  console.log("Question: " + question.getTitle());
  console.log("Number of answers: " + question.getChoices().length);
  var answers = question.getChoices();
  for (var j = 0; j < answers.length; j++) {
    var answer = answers[j];
    console.log(answer.getValue());
    console.log("Is correct answer? " + answer.isCorrectAnswer());
  }
}
function extractCheckbox(item) {
  var question = item.asCheckboxItem();
  console.log("Question: " + question.getTitle());
  console.log("Number of answers: " + question.getChoices().length);
  var answers = question.getChoices();
  for (var k = 0; k < answers.length; k++) {
    var answer = answers[k];
    console.log(answer.getValue());
    console.log("Is correct answer? " + answer.isCorrectAnswer());
  }
}
function extractParagraphText(item) {
  var question = item.asParagraphTextItem();
  console.log("Question: " + question.getTitle());
}
function extractText(item) {
  var question = item.asTextItem();
  console.log("Question: " + question.getTitle());
}
```

If I run this, I am able to extract the questions and answers from the quiz.

Per my understanding, to deploy the add-on, I would need to update the manifest file that includes details of the function that has been created. However, when attempting to update the manifest file, I get the following error: **"appsscript.json" has errors: Invalid manifest: unknown fields: [form]**

I have read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/gsuite-manifests) but I am not getting it.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
  {
  "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "AdSense",
        "version": "v2",
        "serviceId": "adsense"
      }
    ]
  },
  "form": {
    "name": "Extract Q&A",
    "logoUrl": "g",
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#00BCD4",
    "authorizationCheckFunction": "get3PAuthorizationUrls",
    "contextualTriggers": [
      {
        "unconditional": {},
        "onTriggerFunction": "buildAddOn"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want an editor addon or workspace addon and why? Please explain how you plan to use this script in order for us to help us get you there.

Comment: @Neven Subotic: i would want it as a editor add-on

Comment: ok, then you do not to modify the manifest, as this is mainly for Workspace Addons. What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to have this Addon available in one or more Sheets? If more than one Sheet, then I assume you want to click on the Addon and then enter the Form, and then your script should run and write the questions/answers to the Sheet. Please explain what you want to do.